# Azure Logic App - is there a way to debug this issue?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

In Azure Logic Apps, is there any way to do any kind of debugging so I can understand what is (or rather, isn't) happening when I do a test run?

Here's my specific case:

I have a Logic App that connects to a Dropbox account, monitors a folder for any new text files, then writes the contents of that text file to a SQL Server database table.  Pretty simple and straightforward and all that works fine.  But now I'm trying to add a condition before it writes to the database where the contents of the text file has to contain a certain word (Error to be specific).  Adding the step is also simple and straightforward, but no matter what, the condition evaluates to false, even when my string definitely appears in the file.

So what I need to understand is if there is a way I can view the text that the condition is evaluating, similar to being able to view the value of a variable in pretty much any IDE.  I understand the idea of Logic Apps is to greatly reduce or eliminate the need for coding, but this is a basic issue I'm trying to diagnose and this kind of insight to what it's doing seems pretty elementary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I find useful when doing debugging is to use actual variables. Just placing the variable in front of the condition and setting the input data as the same as the condition. This has helped solve so many problems I have had to deal with.

[Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-variables-store-values)

If this doesn’t help, maybe check the code view in this case as there might be a designer bug causing this issue for you.

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I needed and not only did it aid in debugging, but sending it to a variable actually also fixed my issue (sending it to a variable parsed the file contents to a string, which could then be read by the condition, and the keyword found).  Thanks John!!